# События скроллера

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть ли способ узнать, что пользователь потянул именно за скролбар (а не скролит колёсиком мыши)?

Comment: В очередной раз жалею, что в разных браузерах, скрипт может вести себя не так, как хотелось бы. Вроде бы нашёл [простое решение](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/FMKe3/2/). Отлично работает в FF, но в IE и Chrome - работает только первая часть кода, а в Opera - вообще глухо ((

Comment: [Событие onscroll](http://hashcode.ru/questions/117830/)

Answer (score 2):

[Здесь](http://www.adomas.org/javascript-mouse-wheel/) можно почитать про скролл мыши. Собственно, если пользователь дергает скроллбар, то не сработает обработчик `onmousewheel`.

**Добавлено**
Примерный код без оглядки на браузер:

```
function handle(delta){window.delta = 1;}
function wheel(event){
        var delta = 0;
    if(!event)
        event = window.event;
    if(event.wheelDelta)
        delta = event.wheelDelta/120;
    else if(event.detail)
        delta = -event.detail/3;
        if(delta) handle(delta);
}

window.onmousewheel = wheel;
window.onscroll = function(event){if(!window.delta){console.log('scrollbar');}window.delta = 0;}
```

Comment: А если скролит мышью, то сработает и обработчик для скролбара. А так происходить не должно.

Comment: Добавил код.

Comment: Проверил в хроме, не работает

Comment: Проверил в Хроме, работает. Нужна полоса прокрутки, потому что на мышь не реагирует.